# read json file and parse inner json array in java

Tags: java, json, arrays

```
{
"vers": 0.01,
"config": {
    "rate": "perhr",
    "valueColumns": [
        "vCPU",
        "ECU",
        "memoryGiB",
        "storageGB",
        "linux"
    ],
    "currencies": [
        "USD"
    ],
    "regions": [
        {
            "region": "us-east",
            "instanceTypes": [
                {
                    "type": "generalCurrentGen",
                    "sizes": [
                        {
                            "size": "t2.micro",
                            "vCPU": "1",
                            "ECU": "variable",
                            "memoryGiB": "1",
                            "storageGB": "ebsonly",
                            "valueColumns": [
                                {
                                    "name": "linux",
                                    "prices": {
                                        "USD": "0.013"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "size": "t2.small",
                            "vCPU": "1",
                            "ECU": "variable",
                            "memoryGiB": "2",
                            "storageGB": "ebsonly",
                            "valueColumns": [
                                {
                                    "name": "linux",
                                    "prices": {
                                        "USD": "0.026"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Hi, i wanted to read this json file. I tried various ways from google but getting a null at `valuesColumns`. I have to read `sizes` array and have to put in list.

Comment: Did you read this? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html

Comment: And this: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/java-json-parser-example/

Comment: just i will have look at this. thanks @Ivan

Comment: You need to be more specific. What have you tried so far and what exactly are you attempting to get from "valuesColumns"?

Comment: actually i need to get size, vcpu, ecu etc values. I am not able to parse inner array of json. @JaredRummler

Answer (score 1):

I think it will help your cause if you format your json. As it is it's quite hard to read. Googling for a JSON beautifier quickly found me [this one](http://jsonmate.com/).

When working with JSON your browser console provides a nice environment for inspecting and playing with the data. I pasted it into the browser console and did (hit enter after each line):

```
var x = { ... paste JSON here ... } 
x
x.config
x.config.valueColumns
```

This tells me that `x` is a JSON object, `config` is a JSON object and `valueColumns` is a JSON array

Now to java. Grab yourself a json library, and accessing `valueColumns` will be something like:

```
JSONObject x = new JSONObject("{ ... JSON string ... }");
JSONObject config = x.getJSONObject("config");
JSONArray valueColumns = config.getJSONArray("valueColumns");
```

You can then iterate over `valueColumns` and pull out what you need.

Note that the above only gets you to the first `valueColumns` array under `config`. By following the same principle you can go deeper into the structure and get out the `valueColumns` for the objects in the `sizes` array if that's what you're really after.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing json to java there are simple step.
Below code snippet may help you.

```
// parse json to java
Object obj = parser.parse(s);
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) obj;

        JSONObject o = (JSONObject) json.get("config");
        //get json array.
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) o.get("valueColumns");
        System.out.println(array.toJSONString());
        //access element by index 
        System.out.println(array.get(0));
```